# Being asked to take up a part-time status

Tags: graduate-school, part-time

**TL;DR**

**I want to maintain full time status *for now* but my department is asking me to switch to part time status, I'm not certain that is a good idea since international students need to maintain a full time status. I'm being asked to sign and hand over a form giving up my power to be a FT student. I realize my mistake back then was responding positively when they asked the first time around if I wanted a PT status change or not (it was something I was considering, but it seems it may not be the best option, even that aside the window to make such a decision is pretty vast, stretching all the way into the Fall semester)**

**It is nobody's fault, they may be only trying to help me their own way, but I also need to maintain my visa status.**

I'm an international grad student at a US school.

So since the next semester might be my last, I was inquiring for a part-time (PT) status with my department. I wanted to know how it worked, but apparently, I didn't even have to ask, because they started forcing it on me. The administrative assistant in my department kept shooting me regular emails asking me to sign a form for something THEN AND THERE (for something which did not have any urgency), only stopped after I called them out on it. This sort of got my attention.

So I looked into it.

Intl students can only go part-time on their last semester, this is because of an (obscure) rule (which no one informed me of, but I had to dig out on my own) which states that if an intl grad student goes part-time, they cannot be allowed to re-enroll as full time. That is, after going part-time, re-enrolling as full time becomes a void act.

So if I were to go part-time and wanted to stay on for whatever reason, I wouldn't be able to.

Okay let's say this is fine, but this is something which can be decided before the next semester, which is 3.5 months away and can be done anytime within the next two months. So what is the problem? They're asking me to DO IT NOW. Mind you, if I were to fill in that form and submit it, I hand over all power regarding my student status (WHICH CANNOT BE RESTORED) and THEY'RE BREATHING DOWN MY NECK using every tactic they can into pressuring me to hand it over.

Yes, I know everything that is associated with being a full-time student and am fine with it (and may have even considered, but only considered a PT status) but I'm not really comfortable doing something this major and unchangeable in one go THIS QUICKLY.

So what else is wrong at this point? Remember what I said about the form and how it can be submitted anytime before the Fall semester (at least a few weeks before, by then I can definitely let them know). Thing is, they're forcing me to adhere by a non-existent deadline and HAND IT OVER NOW, this is straight up coercion, I've already submitted forms which keep me on as a regular student, but they're sending me threatening emails marked with underlined and bolded red text to hand over power regarding my student status.

They're using a classic pressure tactic of giving me like 2 days to submit it or go bust (for now at least).

This sucks. **I want to let them know that if there is such a change, I will declare it to them well before time (and give them ample time to process it) but not the way they're going about this ( I want to have standard status for now )**. It almost seems to me that they're very interested in sending me to PT status and doing so IMMEDIATELY (leaving me unable to change it back once that happens).

I have only been able to dig a few things up, but not more than that, plus mostly everyone is either deflecting or tight-lipped about stuff like this. Nor am I really sure about all the exact formal nor informal consequences + rules associated with a thing such as this, **so how to let them know that it's fine what they're asking and I may be all for it, just that it's inappropriate for them to hound me like this for something this ultimate/final when there's no real hurry? (given that this is a major decision, I'm not blaming anyone, if it seems okay, I'll let them know well ahead of time and they'll also get what they want, so it's a win-win, just that I get all the opportunity to consider it as much as is allowed by the university )** Also if anyone has any other info about PT status and if they have been a PT student / know someone who has been one, please let me know.

I can't really say that I need more time, then they'll use that against me and definitely try and get a YES out of me.

Comment: I didn't read your too long question because it's too long and because you don't even mention in which country you are.

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! Would you please highlight what is exactly your question? What is *"Intl"* ? What is *FT student*? What is *PT status*?

Comment: Heh...International

Comment: What if you just ignore them?

Comment: Please add the country reference and state your exact question. Are you asking how to resist pressure from the administrative office who wants you to become a part time student?

Comment: Welcome, and good luck! Your question may get closed if people still think it's unclear what you're asking, and it's off-topic to just ask for general advice. @Magicsowon has a great suggestion you may want to [edit] in. You haven't mentioned your advisor/supervisor. Have they been involved? If not, make sure you communicate to them why you want to think this through carefully; they are more likely to understand and support you. Further, consider a [charm offensive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/charm_offensive) toward the admin associate.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it readable.

Comment: @Mark They're threatening to not process / sign my List of Coursework (POS) form for the next semester

Comment: Obviously, you did not read @aparente001 's answer before you wrote this new version of the question.

Comment: @scaaahu - I'm actually a little confused about that.  At some point (two hours ago?) it looks like OP took almost everything out and wrote basically a one-paragraph bare bones question.  Then apparently rolled back to the previous (full-length) version.  It looks as though perhaps OP tried to do a severe pruning, and then rolled back to the full text, perhaps in preparation for a more fine-grained rewrite. I suggest we wait a while and see what OP decides to do with the "manuscript" before responding.

Comment: Does going part-time affect your funding? If you're international, is it allowed under your visa?

Comment: @cactus_pardner I'm sorry I don't see how a charm offensive is relevant here? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @mkennedy I'm not sure if it is allowed under my VISA

Comment: @moin Sometimes people bake cookies "for the office," or offer to get a cup of coffee for the admin associate, etc. Nothing big enough to be a bribe, but it says, "You're a human being who's probably stressed." Hopefully the admin will mutually acknowledge your humanity: you're not delaying because you don't care or to cause problems, but you want to get this right. IF you talk in person, it might be good to say, "I'm checking with the International student office to double-check how this affects my visa." Something so that you can resist the pressure to do the paperwork then and there.

Comment: What is the deadline for getting the signature for the course list? // I suggest replacing "asked" with "pushed" in the title.  It's stronger than "asked" but weaker than "coerced."

Answer (score 8):

> How to let them know that it's fine what they're asking and I may be all for it, just that it's inappropriate for them to hound me like this for something this ultimate/final when there's no real hurry?

- Without caps except the normal ones (abbreviations, beginning of sentence, etc.)
- Without boldface
- Without anything remotely resembling bad language ("suck" is a no-no)
- Without exclamation points
- With *at most* one repetition of one item (preferably, no repetitiveness)
- With calmness and dignity -- do not let them smell fear or desperation
- By responding to emails with at least a 12-hour delay -- preferably 24 hours
- By stating something positive in each interaction, e.g. "I would be happy to meet with an administrator about this"
- By being at least as polite as them
- By calling their bluff, e.g. "If there are any departmental or university policies that could affect my decision, I would appreciate a copy or a link"
- By moving up the hierarchy (one rung at a time) if need be (e.g. go from administrative assistant to chair, assistant chair or director of graduate studies)

Also recommended:

- Ask your advisor for guidance
- Keep your advisor apprised of problems, developments, plans

I'm speaking from experience.  If you can follow the above guidelines, you will have an easier time staying on an even keel through this, and you'll be more effective.

I strongly encourage you to practice presenting your case in the style and format I'm recommending,

#### by editing your post.

Remember, the most effective style is succinct, polite, calm, dignified.  (If it comes out a little stuffy, so be it.)

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately you are responsible for yourself, as you have already found out.

You know what the rules are, so if you feel you are being unduly pressured, then you need to bring other people into the loop in your response. Talk to your advisor as well as whoever is responsible for overseeing PhD students in your program. Include them in your response to the administrative assistant. Also, when writing, show that you know what you’re talking about. Many times people acting in such a manner rely on the lack of knowledge of others to get what they want. You’ve done your homework and know your rights. That gives you an advantage. Use it.